# Как вручную подключить phpoffice PhpSpreadsheet не через composer?

Tags: php

У меня такая ситуация, нет возможности поставить композер, да и php я начал осваивать сравнительно недавно. А описание по установке написано только для композера.

Можно ли его поставить вручную и как потом подключать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете склонировать репозиторий вручную, но все равно придется использовать композер для phpoffice так он не будет работать без своих зависимостей. Их конечно тоже можно попробовать скачать вручную, но лучше рашите проблему невозможности поставить composer.

Comment: Спасибо, тогда буду решать